# nginx rewrite url on language selection

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite urls in nginx but I'm not able to find a common rule for all the pages. I have these url: 

`example.com/
example.com/contact/
example.com/signup/`

When I want to switch languages I just append ?lang=de to them and it works fine, but I want instead 
`example.com/de/ 
example.com/contact/de/ 
example.com/signup/de/`

Is there a way to do it easily without make a rule for each url for each language?